# Swift 3 Parse JSON into UITableView using URLSession

Tags: json, swift, urlsession

I am trying to parse JSON using URLSession and without using Alamofire or anything else.

I just want to take the JSON and put it into a UITableView.

I am trying to piece together what I learned from learning how to Parse JSON using Alamofire with what I can find on google. Many of the answers on youtube or Stack etc use NS for everything..NSURL, NSDictionary, etc etc..Or are just typing code without explaining what/why.

I THINK I am almost there, but I need help understanding what I have left to do.

SO.

I Allowed arbitrary loads in the plst

In a Swift File I have the following

```
class Potter {

private var _title: String!
private var _author: String!
private var _imageURL: String!

let POTTER_URL = "http://de-coding-test.s3.amazonaws.com/books.json"

var title: String {
  if _title == nil {
    _title = ""
  }
  return _title
}

var author: String {
  if _author == nil {
    _author = ""
  }
  return _author
}

var imageURL: String {
  if _imageURL == nil {
    _imageURL = ""
  }
  return _imageURL
}

  func downloadJSON() {


    let url = URL(string: POTTER_URL)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

      if error != nil {
        print("Error")

      } else {

        if let content = data {
          do {
            if let jDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

              if let title = jDict["title"] as? String {
                self._title = title.capitalized

              }

              if let author = jDict["author"] as? String {
                self._author = author.capitalized
              }

              if let imgURL = jDict["imageURL"] as? String {
                self._imageURL = imgURL
              }
            }
          }
          catch {  
          }
        }
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

In my Main.Storyboard I added the tableview and set up all the UI, and in my ViewController I have set up the tableview delegates.

I created a property of

```
var potters = [Potter]()
```

I am stuck now on how to I populate this array, and how do I set up the proper threading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your model is <strike>insane</strike> pretty weird.

In Swift **never** use backed private variables to get read/only properties. And **never** declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional because you are too lazy to write an initializer.

The entire model can be reduced to

```
class Potter {

    let title, author, imageURL: String

    init(title: String, author: String, imageURL : String) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.imageURL = imageURL
    }
}
```

If you would use a `struct`, it's even

```
struct Potter {
    let title, author, imageURL: String
}
```

because you get the memberwise initializer for free.

---

Secondly, put the method `downloadJSON()` out of the model and put it in the controller and call it in `viewDidLoad()`.

In the controller declare the download URL and the data source array

```
let POTTER_URL = "http://de-coding-test.s3.amazonaws.com/books.json"

var books = [Potter]()
```

---

Your method `downloadJSON()` cannot work because the JSON object is an array (`[]`), not a dictionary (`{}`). You need a loop to iterate thru the items, get the values, create a `Potter` item respectively and append it to the data source. If a value does not exist, an empty string is assigned. Finally reload the table view on the main thread.

```
func downloadJSON() {

    let url = URL(string: POTTER_URL)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("DataTask error", error!)

        } else {
            do {
                if let bookData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:String]] {
                    books.removeAll() // clear data source array
                    for book in bookData {
                        let title = book["title"] ?? ""
                        let author = book["author"] ?? ""
                        let imgURL = book["imageURL"] ?? ""
                        books.append(Potter(title: title, author: author, imageURL: imgURL))
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Serialization error", error)
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Two notes:

- The standard JSON dictionary in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`, in this particular case it's even `[String:String]`.
- `.mutableContainers` is useless if the containers are only read and useless in Swift anyway because the object cannot be casted to `NSMutableArray / -Dictionary` and you get mutability for free using a `var`iable.

Comment: @vadian...solid answer, but take it easy on the poor guy. He is simply asking to learn :)

Comment: I meant as in no need for the harsh language "e.g.: insane, lazy, etc.." But it's not that big of a deal. :)

Comment: @UnisBarakat I attenuated *insane* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

1. The web services returns an array of objects: `[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]`.
2. It will be easier if you create a `init` method with a dictionary as parameter.
3. The `downloadJSON` is an async task, using `completionHandler` is the best way. And if you want to place the `downloadJSON` in the `Potter` class, it should be a `static` function.
4. Final, you should handle the result like this:

   ```
   Potter.downloadJSON { potters in

       self.potters = potters

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
   }
   ```

The final code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var potters = [Potter]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Potter.downloadJSON { potters in

            self.potters = potters

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return potters.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!

        let potter = potters[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = potter.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = potter.author

        return cell
    }
}

class Potter {

    private var _title: String!
    private var _author: String!
    private var _imageURL: String!

    static let POTTER_URL = "http://de-coding-test.s3.amazonaws.com/books.json"

    var title: String {
        if _title == nil {
            _title = ""
        }
        return _title
    }

    var author: String {
        if _author == nil {
            _author = ""
        }
        return _author
    }

    var imageURL: String {
        if _imageURL == nil {
            _imageURL = ""
        }
        return _imageURL
    }

    init(dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        self._title = dict["title"] as? String
        self._imageURL = dict["imageURL"] as? String
        self._author = dict["author"] as? String
    }

    class func downloadJSON(completion: @escaping (_ potters: [Potter]) -> Void) {

        let url = URL(string: POTTER_URL)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error")

            } else {

                if let content = data {

                    do {
                        if let jArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                            var potters = [Potter]()
                            for jDict in jArray {
                                let potter = Potter(dict: jDict)
                                potters.append(potter)
                            }
                            completion(potters)
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The method `downloadJSON()` should be implemented in the `ViewController` since it is returning the array of `Potter` data. Then in the `URLSession` response you should create one array which will be act as the tableview datasource. (i.e `self.arrTableData  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [[String : AnyObject]]`)

Then in for the tableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection sectionIndex: Int) -> Int {

        return self.arrTableData.count
}
```

and in cell for row at index path

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   //create `potters` object with the value and use it else you can direcly use the value of objects as below.
     let dictPotters = self.arrTableData[indexPath.row]
      let title = dictPotters["title"]
  }
```

Thanks